# Different MaxLength values

Tags: php, textfield, maxlength

I have an options panel in my WordPress theme with several text fields. For example: Project title, Project description, Twitter username, etc.

```
case 'text':
    $val = $value['std'];
    $std = get_option($value['id']);
    if ( $std != "") { $val = $std; }
    $output .= '<input class="" maxlength="12" name=""'. $value['id'] .'" id="'. $value['id'] .'" type="'. $value['type'] .'" value="'. $val .'" />';
break;
```

As the above code shows... I currently have my max length for the text fields as 12, but I would like to have a max length to be different for each of the text fields. How can I do this?

The input IDs for the text fields are mytheme_projectitle1, mytheme_projectitle2, mytheme_projectitle3, mytheme_twitterusername etc. I don't have an input class for any of them, just the ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the id for each element with `$value['id']` as is apparent from the code. Use that to derive a maximum length, for example this way:

```
case 'text':
    // Overrides for the default value of maxlength
    $maxlengths = array(
        'mytheme_projecttitle1' => 10,
        'mytheme_projecttitle2' => 20,
    );

    // If there is an override value use it; otherwise use the default of 12
    $maxlen = isset($maxlengths[$value['id']]) ? $maxlengths[$value['id']] : 12;

    $val = $value['std'];
    $std = get_option($value['id']);
    if ( $std != "") { $val = $std; }

    $output .= '<input class="" maxlength="'.$maxlength.'"..."; // the rest as before
```